# Memcache safe for multiple clients access

Tags: python, memcached, multiprocessing

Suppose multiple python processes/clients attempt to do something like this at uncontrollable times.

```
cache.set("GLOBAL_KEY", Value)
```

Is it this safe or there's a chance to obtain corrupted values ?

Provided this is not safe ,what techniques are available for protecting values against clients concurrent access ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged as `multiprocessing` I'm only referring to these type of parallel process.

That said, there are [a couple of ways](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to share a value or a *state*:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Lock

def f(n, a, l):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        l.acquire(()
        try:
          a[i] = -a[i]
        finally:
            l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))
    lock = Lock()

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr, lock))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

Do mind that you need to share value and to [control concurrent access](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes).